# Bot Framework - Enterprise Template .bot file missing

Tags: botframework

I just started with Enterprise Bot Template in Visual Studio, I do not see the bot configuration file to be created (the .bot file) as and when I create the project, should I add this manually? if yes is there any specific reason cause of which this is omitted. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition for the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divya Akula, it sounds like you haven't run the `msbot clone...` command yet.

We don't provide an empty `.bot` file for the Enterprise Bot template, it is something that is created and populated with the CLI Tools.

To find the full `msbot` command that you should run, take a look at the `readme.md` file, and it will instruct you on the values that you need to fill in (e.g. `luisAuthoringKey`, `YOUR_LOCALE_FOLDER`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, I wanted to test an enterprise bot template with a bot file and had a no clue. This is how I figured it out.

Ope bot emulator --> New Bot Configuration --> Bot Name --> enter the endpoint url (http://localhost:3978/api/messages usually this url) and click save and connect. Your bot should now open in the emulator